# Galleria and JQuery Swipe. Y control?

Tags: jquery, ipad, swipe, galleria

Trying to run Galleria and Swipe in JQuery.

Example can be found at: http://www.mikelastphoto.com/ipad/

Problem: Everything works, except for the swipe taking over control of the entire page on the iPad. I don't mind if I can't pinch/zoom (although that would be nice) but I am unable to swipe along the Y axis to view the rest of the thumbnails at the bottom of the page. Essentially I would like the swipe to only be possible on the image itself, and swiping up and down to scroll like normal.

I believe the problem is in this statement inside JQuery.Swipe.js.

```
        // Done Swiping
        // Swipe should only be on X axis, ignore if swipe on Y axis
        // Calculate if the swipe was left or right
        function touchEnd(event) {
            console.log('Ending swipe gesture...')
            var changeY = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y
            if(changeY < defaults.threshold.y && changeY > (defaults.threshold.y*-1)) {
                changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x

                if(changeX > defaults.threshold.x) {
                    defaults.swipeLeft()
                }
                if(changeX < (defaults.threshold.x*-1)) {
                    defaults.swipeRight()
                }
            }
        }
```

Because the Y is just being ignored, but not being left to Safari to interpret.

```
$(document).swipe({
     swipeRight: function() { $.galleria.prev(); return false; },
     swipeLeft: function() { $.galleria.next(); return false; },
  });
```

Is this the section I will need to apply the swipe just to the jpeg and not the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `$(document).swipe(event)` try applying it just to your div `$(#yourdiv).swipe(event)`